# Why is eval evil in makefiles

Tags: makefile, eval

I have had several people tell me at this point that eval is evil in makefiles.  I originally took their word for it, but now I'm starting to question it.   Take the following makefile:

```
%.o:
    $(eval targ=$*)
    echo making $targ

%.p:
    echo making $*
```

I understand that if you then did `make "a;blah;".o`, then it would run `blah` (Which could be an `rm -rf \`, or worse).   However, if you ran `make "a;blah;".p` you would get the same result without the eval.   Furthermore, if you have permissions to run make, you would also have permissions to run `blah` directly as well, and wouldn't need to run make at all.   So now I'm wondering, is `eval` really an added security risk in makefiles, and if so, what should be avoided?

Comment: Always use quotes around strings you pass to `echo`.

Comment: The "`eval` is evil" meme is usually a PHP or JavaScript thing, I get the feeling whoever suggested this to you simply decided it applies to make as well without giving it much thought.

Comment: eval is good in Perl - see exceptions

Comment: Never allow people to pass judgments. Judgements are worthless. It's the motivations that count. They allow you to decide for yourself. So always, when someone makes a claim like this, ask them why, and don't let them evade the answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Why is `eval` evil?

Because it grants a whole power of language to things you actually don't want to give that power.

Often it is used as "poor man's metaprogramming" to construct some piece of code and then run it. Often it looks like `eval("do stuff with " + thing)` - and thing is only known during runtime, because it gets supplied from outside.

However, if you don't make sure that `thing` belongs to some tiny subset of language you need in that particular case (like, is a string representation of one valid name), your code would grant permissions to stuff you didn't intend to. For example, if `thing` is `"apples; steal all oranges"` then oranges would be stolen.

If you *do* make sure that `thing` belongs to some subset of language you actually need then 2 problems arise:

- You are reimplementing language features (parsing source) which is not DRY and is often a sign of misusing a language.
- If you resort to this that means simpler means are not suitable and your use case is somewhat complicated which makes validating your input harder.

Thus, it's really easy to break security with `eval` and taking enough precautions to make it safe is hard, that's why if you see an `eval` you should suspect possible security flaw. That's just a heuristic, not a law.

`eval` is a very powerful tool - as powerful as the whole language - and it's too easy to shoot your leg off with it.

### Why this particular use of `eval` is not good?

Imagine a task that requires making some steps that depend on a file. Task can be done with various files. (like, user gives Virtualbox image of a machine that is to be brought up and integrated into existing network infrastructure)
Imagine, say, lazy administrator that automated this task - all commands are written in a makefile because it fits better than sh script (some steps depend on other and sometimes don't need to be re-done).
Administrator made sure that all commands are ok and correct and had given sudoers permission to run `make` with that specific makefile. Now, if makefile contains string like yours then using properly crafted name for your Virtualbox image you could pwn the system, or something like that.

Of course, I had to stretch far to make this particular case a problem, but it's a potential problem anyway.

Makefiles usually offer simple contracts: you name the target and some very specific stuff - written in makefile - gets done. Using `eval` the way you've used it offers a different contract: the same stuff as above but you also can supply commands in some complicated way and they would get executed too.

You could try patching the contract by making sure that `$*` would not cause any trouble. Describing what that means exactly could be an interesting exercise in language if you want to keep as much flexibility in target names as possible.

Otherwise, **you should be aware of extended contract** and don't use solutions like this in cases where that extension would cause problems. If you intend your solution to be reusable by as many people as possible, you should make its contract cause as little problems as possible, too.

Comment: While I understand what you're saying, in your scenario, the security hole exists whether you use `(eval targ=*)` or if you use `echo $*` in the recipe -- so eval does not introduce a security hole that doesn't exist elsewhere.   I'm thinking that make in general would be riddled with these holes, so I'm not sure that eval is necessarily more evil than make in general.

Comment: @John I'd say that `echo $*` is in same venue of "evil" as `eval` itself for basically same reasons. Makefile that uses neither (and other similar stuff) can have nice and limited contract, so make is not "evil" in general.
In many cases you would get away with extended contracts - just say that reaction to some funky input is undefined behaviour and pass responsibility of validating the input onto your users. However, sometimes you would not, and then you should be careful with `eval` because that's a gateway for trouble into your runtime, it should be guarded accordingly.

Comment: As for make being riddled with stuff like this - yes, there's a possibility.
There's a situation when some subset of strings - sql queries, http get requests, regular expressions, HTML, or subsets of those - get treated as if they were strings. However, operations that have closure on strings sometimes don't have closure on these subsets. Using those operations results in trouble and those rakes are too easy to step on.\
Make (and bash too) make working with commands as if they were strings super-easy. There is an inherent problem with this, but that's also very convenient.

Comment: The default rule for .c to .o files has an unquoted `$@` in it, so yes, there are many such instances (though I agree with your convenient comment).  I think giving users extra permissions to run make would be the actual security hole.